# VC++ Runtime on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, pinvoke

I have a .NET app which invoke W32's API (msvcrt40.dll) through P/Invoke. Under Linux Mono, the app crashed with DllNotFoundException on msvcrt40.dll load. I'd looked into Wine to search for msvcrt40 shared lib but only found fake dll which is useless. My question is:

- Is there any msvcrt40 equivalent lib under Linux that works?

**UPDATE --------------**

The APIs in used are:

```
_mbcjistojms
_mbcjmstojis
_ismbblead
```

Using dumpbin to look into msvcrt40.dll. I found that it forward my calls to msvcrt.dll, which was substituted by libc.so.6. Again, using objdump to look into libc-2-12.so to find above APIs. Unfortunately, there ain't exports for those APIs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those APIs are not existed on Linux. But fortunately I found source code of those functions, hence re-write them in C# way. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any msvcrt40 equivalent lib under Linux that works?

Very unlikely that there is a full direct replacement of that very old MSVC runtime.

The way forward is to find out what functions are being called, and find a way to implement the same functionality in a natural way on the target platform. Perhaps the functionality can be readily implemented using the Mono framework. Or perhaps you can use the platform's C runtime.

**Update**

According to your comments you just need to perform some conversions between different code pages. Use the `Encoding` class for that.

Comment: I found that msvcrt40 forward API call to msvcrt.dll which equivalent to Linux libc. Using objdump to dump export symbols from libc to see if it supports API i'd used (ismbblead; mbcjistojms; mbcjmstojis). But, unfortunately it wasn't. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think you need to understand why you are performing these p/invoke calls. Do you need them? Are you really doing Windows MBCS conversions on Linux? Why? Where does MBCS come into your program. Fundamentally I don't think you should be tackling the problem by trying to find exact replacement for these MSVC runtime functions. You should understand what the program needs to do and find a native Mono way to do it.

Comment: Well, I hope I could forget about those p/invokes. The windows app is a data converter written in C# which convert data encoded by Shift_JIS to UTF. Under Linux, I have 0 exp with unicode/multibyte string convert. That's why I tried to find those symbols in linux's libs.

Comment: Converting from Shift JIS to a Unicode encoding shouldn't be hard. Can't you use `Encoding.GetEncoding(932)`?

Comment: I know, it's quite simple to convert a string from one encoding to another encoding back & forth. But in my situation, it's a bit harder. The data coming from binary file instead.

Comment: I don't see how that matters. Anyway, I think I answered the question that you asked.